# Seperate one part list into four part list with Python

Tags: python, string, list, split

The program I've created prints out the list:

```
['2    19   2839475239874 hda']
```

It was supposed to look like this:

```
['2','19','2839475239874','hda']
```

So instead of having a list with four parts to it, I have one big part. What can I do to separate my list, so that it has four parts?

Thanks! I've been working at this for a while now, and I haven't found any answers that actually work.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe the problem isn't "my list is supposed to look like this and doesn't", perhaps it is, "why isn't the list in four parts when I generate it?"

Comment: There may be way to create the list as you expect instead of splitting it after. Can you show how you are creating the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
['2 19 2839475239874 hda'][0].split()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the string at whitespaces:

```
>>> lis = ['2 19 2839475239874 hda']
>>> lis[0].split()
['2', '19', '2839475239874', 'hda']
```

help on `str.split`:

```
>>> print (str.split.__doc__)
S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings

Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the
delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are
removed from the result.
```